# Xcode 15 freezes often

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm developing for the iPhone and I'm not sure what's going on but simple tasks cause Xcode to freeze. Some of those tasks include scrolling, searching for and replacing text, refactor/rename, opening a file, etc.

Most of the time the Xcode will freeze for about 30 seconds or so. Sometimes the app will freeze indefinitely and I'll have to force quit.

The strange thing is that this only occurs on some files. And some files are so bad that I'll have to open them with another editor just so I can scroll without the app locking up.

I have tried deleting the app and supporting files twice now with no luck. Most recently I have upgraded to Xcode 15.0.1 and still no luck.

Has anyone else had this issue with Xcode 15? I had no issue with Xcode 14.

Comment: Do you have enough system memory? I have 16Gb on my laptop, however since upgrading from Xcode 14 to 15 its been running out during Xcode activities if there's a couple of other apps/browsers open.

Comment: @Piepants Thanks for the comment but I have plenty of free memory on my 32GB M2. I still have the issue even if I close all other apps.

Comment: I'm also seeing this, and the worse part is that cpu and memory usage are quite low :/

Comment: @JoséManuelSánchez Interesting, my cpu is over 100%.

Comment: Xcode 15.0.1 caused my iphone XS froze on white screen with error: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error. The phone does not respond to anything even after disconnecting cable and hard reset also not working.